# Create workflow service instances for large number of records at once

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric, batch-processing

I’m working on a business problem which has to import files which has 1000s of records. Each record has to be registered in a Workflow as individual record which has to go through its own workflow.

WF4 [Corporate Purchase Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd807514%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) example has a good solution, as in the first step it create bookmarks for all the required record ids. So the workflow can be resumed with rest of the actions for each individual record/id.

1. I would like to know how to implement same thing using Workflow services as I could get the benefits of AppFabric for my workflows.
2. Is there any other solutions to handle batch of records/ids? Otherwise workflow service has to be called 1000s of times just to register every record in a workflow instance which is a not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to implement same thing using Workflow services as I could get the benefits of AppFabric for my workflows.

This is pretty straight forward. You're going to have one workflow that reads the file and loops through the results using the looping activities that exist. Then, inside the loop you'll be starting up the workflow that each record needs **(the "Service")** by calling the endpoint with a `Send` activity.

Now, as for the workflow that is the Service, you're going to have a `Receive` activity at the top of the workflow that also has `CanCreateInstance` set the `true`. The everything after the `Receive` is no different than any other workflow. You may consider having a `Send` activity right after the `Receive` just to let the caller know that the Service has been started. But that's not a requirement -- the `Receive` will be required because it forces WF to build the workflow to use the `WorkflowServiceHost`.

> Is there any other solutions to handle batch of records/ids? Otherwise workflow service has to be called 1000s of times just to register every record in a workflow instance which is a not a good solution.

Are you indicating that a for a web server to receive 1000's of requests is not a good solution? Consider the fact that an IIS server can handle roughly 25-50 requests, per **instant** in time, **per core**. Now consider the fact that you're loop that's loading the workflows isn't going to average more than **maybe** 5 in that **instant** of time but probably more like 1 or 2.

I don't think the web server is going to be your issue. I've started up literally 10,000's of workflows on a server via a loop just like the one you're going to build and it didn't break a sweat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. My business problem starts after a file import. Lets say this requirement needs to process Invoices of other companies. So my solution has to start workflow for each invoice which will go though its own set of steps based on the process given by the original owner of the invoice. Therefore I'm looking for options for calling WF service after file import.

Comment: @Koolb, same principal, it's just that the outer workflow doesn't import the file and gets its list from somewhere else. Either way you need an orchestrator to startup each individual workflow. Make sense?

Comment: Yes. I agree sending the list of ids to a outer workflow would be the best solution. However I need to create bookmarks for each id by the second workflow. Then I may have to call Receive method of inner workflow in a loop to create automatic bookmarks but I may have the option of net.pipes for performance.

Comment: @Koolb, I don't understand your issue surrounding bookmarks. A `Receive` activity creates a bookmark and idle's the workflow. Further, a `Delay` activity does the same. There are many different options when building workflow services for bookmarking and idling the flows for later. And correlation isn't an issue, each workflow ___very simply___ correlates on the id, that's as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use WCF's MSMQ binding to launch your workflows. Requests can come in normally through HTTP, and WCF would route them to MSMQ and process the load. You can throttle how many workflow instances are used through the MSMQ binding + IIS settings.

Download this word document that describes setting up a workflow application with WCF and MSMQ: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21245

Comment: I haven't thought about queues. It should be a good solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of the doing the simplest thing that could work, you can bring the subworkflow in as an activity to the main workflow and use a parallel for each to execute the branch for each input from your file. No extra invoking is required and the tooling supports this out of the box because all workflows are activities. Hosting the main process in a service so you can avoid contention with the rest of your IIS users, real people that they may are, might be a good idea.

I do agree that calling IIS or a WCF service 1000's of times is not a problem though, unless you want to do it in a few seconds!

It is important to remember that one of the good things about workflow is that it has fairly low overhead (compared to other workflow products) so you should be more concerned about what your workflow does than just the idea of launching lots of instances. The idea of batches like your example is very common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My solution has to process large number of invoices as part of the business problem. Invoice owner could be different and each invoices go though the steps given by its owner. However good that you clarify low overhead of wf. I can think of a solution based on it.